# Spring secutiry CAS SSO every time its asks login credentials

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

CAS single sign on is not working. After  login when we navigate to other apps from app1(Home page)every time its asks login credentials to access the app2 from app1.

Comment: Please provide more info like, what version of spring, CAS you are using and the configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds close "sendRenew" parameter being set to Yes.

check the following link,
[CAS asking authentication for each application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601640/cas-asking-authentication-for-each-application/45222728#45222728)

If the above link doesn't work, you may need to share your spring-security configuration details on both apps.